# Linux USB tethering (from Linux to Android)

Tags: linux, usb, internet, connection-sharing

In most cases people would like to tether internet connection from an Android device to Linux, but I need to tether connection from Linux to Android.

- I have car head unit running Android 8.1
- LTE USB modem
- and I need small computer to run Linux.

I'd like to connect USB modem to Linux and tether internet connection by an other USB port to Android head unit. Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: Your Linux computer should run in USB device/gadget mode which is not very likely because PCs are built with USB host controllers, not device controllers. Secondly your Android device must support the USB internet device (e.g. RNDIS) which is even more unlikely as the kernel won't recognize it.

Comment: Thx for the answer, my android device supports RNDIS, but what about non PC computers for an example can I buy raspberry pi to connect it to modem and share the internet connection by an other USB port from the connected modem to Android head unit using RNDIS?